# JavaScript: Changing navigation item color after being clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

so I'm working on this cafe site for an OdinProject task and I want to have it so when I click on a nav link it changes color and clicking on another one changes its color and sets the other one back to default.

```
// Importing functions from separate modules
import { createHomeSection } from "./home";
import { createMenuSection } from "./menu";
import { createContactSection } from "./contact";

// Array of navigation links with associated actions and page identifiers
const navigationLinks = [
    { text: "Menu", action: createMenuSection, page: "menu" },
    { text: "Pixel Bites", action: createHomeSection, page: "home" },
    { text: "Contact", action: createContactSection, page: "contact" },
];

// Getting a reference to the content container in the HTML
const contentContainer = document.getElementById("content");

// ***Array to store all navigation links for later use
const allLinks = [];

// Function to create the header navigation menu
function createHeader() {
    // Creating a header element
    const header = document.createElement("header");

    // Looping through the navigationLinks array
    navigationLinks.forEach(({ text, action, page }) => {
        // Creating a paragraph element for each navigation link
        const link = document.createElement("p");
        link.textContent = text;
        link.classList.add("navLinks");

        // Setting an ID for the "Pixel Bites" link to potentially identify it
        if (text === "Pixel Bites") {
            link.id = "headerLogo";
        }

        // Adding a click event listener to each link
        link.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Saving the current page identifier in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("currentPage", page);
           
            // Clearing the content container
            contentContainer.innerHTML = "";

            // ***Resetting the color of all links
            allLinks.forEach(linkItem => {
                linkItem.style.color = "";
            });

            // ***Highlighting the clicked link
            link.style.color = "lightcoral";

            // Rebuilding the header and adding the action content
            contentContainer.appendChild(createHeader());
            contentContainer.appendChild(action());
        });

        // ***Storing each link in the 'allLinks' array
        allLinks.push(link);

        // Appending the link to the header
        header.appendChild(link);
    });

    // Returning the created header
    return header;
}

// Adding the header to the content container
contentContainer.appendChild(createHeader());

// Retrieving the current page identifier from localStorage
const currentPage = localStorage.getItem("currentPage");

// This section is here to make sure that when the page is reloaded it stays on the same page
if (currentPage === "menu") {
    contentContainer.appendChild(createMenuSection());
} else if (currentPage === "contact") {
    contentContainer.appendChild(createContactSection());
} else {
    contentContainer.appendChild(createHomeSection());
}
```

I have tried many ways even one that worked for the menu page with its categories, but the menu section works very differently. That method that is present in the code I have given. Sorry for the bad naming, I ran out of ideas and I used chatGPT to come up with the comments to hopefully make my messy and unoptimized code easier to understand. Thanks in advance!